# Test a series of numbers to ensure they fit the sequence 1,2,3...n

Tags: validation, numbers, sequence

I am trying to find a slightly more elegant solution to find if a sequence of numbers is in order.  This is for a web form, and I am giving the user a chance to number items and that will set up the order.  I know the maximum number of items, and it should always start at one.

Right now (I know it is not correct) I test to make sure all the numbers are different and add up to what it should (e.g. for three items I test it adds to 6).  Does anyone have a better/more accurate (since it is possible to go break mine) solution?  I am using php, but what I really want is logic so your example could be in pseudo-code or any relatively easy to read language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just sort the user-input numbers, and see if they match an index that you increment by 1.

```
nMax = 10
sortedUserArray = Sort(UserArray)

For i = 1 To nMax
    If Not sortedUserArray(i) = i Then
        ' Input not valid. 
        ' Throw an error or something. 
    End If
Next i
```

For the `Sort` part, there exists a variety of sorting algorithms: [Quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort), [Straight insertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_sort), [Heapsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort), etc. Just pick one that fits your needs and do a search to find a ready-made procedure on the web. Your language of choice may even have some built-in sorting algorithms, so you might not even need to look that far.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the maximum number of items, you can avoid a sort by simply allocating a boolean array and populating it. In pseudocode:

```
define numsInOneThruN (int xarr[], int sz):
    # Declare the boolean array and initialise to all false.

    declare isSet[1..sz]
    for all i in 1..sz:
        isSet[i] = false

    # For every number in list, if within range, set boolean value to true.

    for all i in xarr:
        if i >= 1 and i <= sz:
            isSet[i] = true

    # Check that all boolean values are true.

    for all i in 1..sz:
        if not isSet[i]:
            return false

    return true
```

This has the advantage of being `O(n)` time complexity rather than a best-case sort of `O(n log n)` - that probably won't matter for small data sets but it may become important for larger one.

You should also take into account the fact that this has a higher space complexity than an in-place sort since it uses an array equalt to the input size. That makes it `O(n)` space instead of the `O(1)` for the sort option.

As always, you can generally trade off space for time depending on your needs.

Comment: +1 Much less overkill than my answer. Given, though, that we are talking about user-input values, `n` is presumably small (users would want to kill me if I asked them to input >20 ordered numbers), so neither storage space nor computational time is likely to be anywhere on the problem radar in this particular case. But I make a mental note of this as the "proper" solution for the general case.

Comment: @Jean-François, I'm not sure I agree with your "proper" comment, I think it's more a case of this is just a _different_ solution - that doesn't make yours any less valid. I just added this one as an alternative approach. For example, if the numbers had to be 1000, 2000, ... , 999000, then my space-complex solution would be pretty useless. Even if they were contiguous but there were _lots_ of them, it probably up to the user as to whether they want to waste time or space. So +1 right back at ya' - not that I want to get involved in some SO love-in :-)

Comment: "if the numbers had to be 1000, 2000, ... , 999000" then I'd consider doing `isSet[i/1000] = true`. But dividing indices like that is just asking for trouble.

Comment: This "boolean array" is actually a hash, and PHP arrays are hashes, so doing `hash[number] = true` in a loop will generally not waste space.

Comment: Yes, you can _consider_ it as a hash but it's a perfect one with no chance of collisions. That's makes it a bit more efficient than your average run-of-the-mill regular hash.

Answer (score 1):

If you already established that the numbers are all different, just check the minimum and the maximum values. There are only n different numbers which satisfy 1 <= x <= n.